# pg_ctl hangs over ssh

Tags: restore, postgresql-10, virtualisation, ssh

I am designing a process to test my postgresql 10.8 backups by restoring them to a random point in time in a throwaway virtual machine. I have been unable to fully automate the process though. I am blocked at step 8 (section 25.3.4) of [the official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html)

> 8. Start the server.

When executing the `pg_ctl start` over ssh, the command hangs until it is killed. If I ssh directly onto the VM and execute `pg_ctl start`, then the command returns quickly as expected.

[This thread from 2012](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/4F739159.4020808%40consistentstate.com) seems to describe a similar scenario. In my case however the postgres process *does* start successfully even if the calling session is killed while it is hanging (possibly an improvement between 9.0.5 and 10.8 though?).

[This github issue](https://github.com/haskell/process/issues/70) seems relevant but sadly is "solved" by a long rewrite in a language I don't know and concludes finally that it's a bug in the `pg_ctl` binary.

## The Big Question

> How can I automate step 8 so that I can continue on to subsequent validation tests of my backup media?

Is this an outstanding bug in the binary I need to hack around? Or have I missed a sensible implementation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like `pg_ctl` wants a real terminal for output, which is not allocated by `ssh` when you simply ask it to run a command. According to the [Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-pg-ctl.html)

> On Unix-like systems, by default, the server's standard output and standard error are sent to pg_ctl's standard output (not standard error). The standard output of pg_ctl should then be redirected to a file or piped to another process such as a log rotating program like rotatelogs; otherwise `postgres` will write its output to the controlling terminal (from the background) and will not leave the shell's process group. [...] These default behaviors can be changed by using `-l` to append the server's output to a log file. Use of either `-l` or output redirection is recommended.

Therefore, you either need to tell `ssh` to allocate a terminal for `pg_ctl` using the `-t` options (`ssh -t somehost "pg_ctl start"`) or tell `pg_ctl` to *not* write to the terminal (`ssh somehost "pg_ctl start >/dev/null"` or `ssh somehost "pg_ctl start -l /tmp/start.log "`)